# expressjs return a list of item with the same tag

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

My PostSchema is like this:

```
    let PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: String,
    time: Date,
    likes: Number,
    image: String,
    tag: String 
    });

let Post = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);

module.exports = Post;
```

And I'd like to get a list of all the posts with the same tag

---

Here is my code to get it rendered. It is in the folder routes/post

```
    router.get("/tag", function(req, res) {
    Post.find({ subreddit: req.params.tag }).lean()
      .then(posts => {
        res.render("posts/index", { posts });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

---

Of course I have the views/posts folder with index.ejx to route the view

```
    <li class="list-group-item">                
           <div class="text-right">
               <span>Tags: </span><a href="/tag/<%=post.tag%>"><%= post.tag %></a>
           </div>
    </li>
```

I don't really understand how or where I got it wrong. I tried to follow the instruction of the tutorial here: https://www.makeschool.com/academy/track/standalone/reddit-clone-in-node-js/create-subreddits

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to trim the value you search:

```
    router.get("/tag", function(req, res) {
        let tag = req.params.tag;
        if (!tag) {
          throw new Error('No tag was found');
        }

        tag = tag.trim();

        Post.find({ subreddit: req.params.tag }).lean()
          .then(posts => {
            res.render("posts/index", { posts });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
```